# WINAPI. HDC в массив

Tags: winapi

Есть ли способы загрузить массив пикселей из HDC в массив? (желательно типа int с цветом типа 0xFFFFFFFF).
Знаю есть способы, но тут не обойтись без танцев с BITMAP,BITMAPINFO и прочее, что очень неудобно. Например есть легкие способы создать из HDC в BITMAP(где BITMAP автоматически заполняется). Но можно ли как то одной функцией загрузить пиксели из HDC в массив типа int без цикла копирования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, напрямую получить массив пикселей не получится, потому что HDC - это контекст физического устройства, а устройство может представлять пиксели произвольным, иногда очень причудливым образом - вспомнить, например, EGA адаптеры. Или же оно может быть вообще не цветным - доступ к принтеру точно так же идет через HDC.

Этап с выгрузкой массива в BITMAP необходим, точнее, с выгрузкой в DIB (device-independent bitmap). Это как раз и будет преобразованием из неизвестного нам физического представления пикселей в стандартную форму RGB/ARGB.